# Prevent grouping column header in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

i want to make an Crosstab Template for my data.
For each value there is a timestamp, a location and the name of the device from which i get the value. So i am giving a list of values via Java and a JRBeanCollectionDataSource to my report, for the example below this would be 9 values while each of them has 3 additional parameters to place it on the right column/place in the crosstab.
When i give this sort of data to my Jasper Report with a Crosstab (Crosstab is needed cause i don't know how many rows and columns my report will have) in it, Jasper orders/groups the columns and the output looks like this:

[image]

But what i want is to show the data in the sequence i give them to my report, for example:

[image]

I am using Java to fill my report with a JRBeanCollectionDataSource and a self defined DataSource (this works perfect, i am working with this method for months).

Is there any way this kind of column grouping could be prevented? (i have a working crosstab template but i am not able to find the propertie with the help of i can solve my problem)

Hope you people can help me.

Comment: @Alex K  
why you deleted the tag "java"? Cause i fill, compile and parameterize my JasperReportTemplate with Java I think this tag depends here. What if the solution could be a parameter given by the java programm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to tell the crosstab that your data ir already sorted?
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#crosstabDataset

Click the crosstab element, in the Dataset Tab, mark "Data Pre Sorted".

[image]

Comment: I could not find this option, but i did the following on each ColumnGroup i have:
    <columnGroup name="unit" height="20">
     <bucket order="None" class="java.lang.String">
but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe my data could be the problem, they look like this:      

{[time=01.01.2020;location=Vienna;name=Device1;value=5], [time=01.01.2020;location=Berlin;name=Device1;value=3], [time=01.01.2020;location=Vienna;name=Device2;value=6], lkjashgölouashglöos[time=02.01.2020;location=Vienna;name=Device1;value=2], [time=02.01.2020;location=Berlin;name=Device1;value=6], [time=02.01.2020;location=Vienna;name=Device2;value=1], ...}     you can say the data is "Line-Pre-Sorted", would the option "data-presortet" be able to handle such data?

Comment: Thanks, now i found the option
Unfortunately this doen't solve my problem, now the data is displayed in a "crazy" way and the column header is also ordered by jasper reports and i can't comprehend how it comes to this lookalike
Do you know how or from which direction the crosstab is generated, or how the data should be presorted?

Comment: Are you sure about the ordering of your data? Try to print it in detail band to see the ordering jasper is getting.

Comment: yes i am sure about the ordering.
It could be that i have a "solution" but it not realy solves the problem: in the jasper documentation is written that jasper pre-sorts the data in the crosstab and this can't be prevented. There was a way mentioned that you can order it by yourself by writeing your own ordering class but for my needs this is to complex and complicated, so now when i want to order the data by the given input from the user i generate an csv where i can control everything 
Nevertheless thanks for your help.